# WebClient.DownloadString doesn't return correct unicode charactes altough its encoding is set to UTF8

Tags: c#, webclient

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/test.html"));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: thanks, the code in this question and the selected answer already gave me answers to my problems

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: well actually before this only a single character were shown instead of Unicode characters now i got different result some are correct now and those which aren't, are at least different and I can find what to replace it with. but its not still completely correct.

Comment: Whilst probably a fine answer consider adding an explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "UTF-8");
    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    //Do-Something
}
```